# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after rebuilding the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem with my website (ASP.NET WEBFORMS)
After every rebuilding of the project, the browser show me this error.
so every time after rebuilding I need to go to the settings of my browser and clear the cookies of my website. even when I hosted my web site on a server I get the same problem : `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

[image]

so after every rebuilding, I need to clear cookies

[image]

Please, how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: I see that you use SSL. Can you recreate the self-signed certificate and try again? Also: Does this happen with all browsers?

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand what do you mean about 'SSL', and yes, this happen with all browsers

Comment: SSL, you are using "https" instead of "http".

Comment: can i create self-signed certificate using windows10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I were checking if the user is connected using this property : `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in the page of connection, if true, redirect to home page.
I change it to Session variable and its works good now